# How do I change lenses without damaging my camera?

Tags: lens, canon

As I have an canon camera in which I even got standard kit lens. Now at present the lens of camera is been not working properly because of not handling it safety, due to which I am not able to get proper or clear image or pictures.
So can any help me out that how to change the lens without damaging my camera.

Comment: Is this about damage to the camera? Or damage to the lens? Can you define "not handling it safely"? Did you drop the lens?

Comment: It is with regard to damage to the camera.

Comment: DSLR cameras are made for changing lenses often, I have changed mine at least a thousand times (before I started to hate it so I bought a second body). Chances are slim that this would damage the camera (outside of obvious issues like dropping it or getting dirt inside)

Comment: Talk to a photo shop capable of repairing your camera if needed.

Comment: Can you elaborate in what happened to your lens? What exactly was "not handling it safely", and what do your results look like now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifted from the page given by Surendar above.

http://www.digitalcameraworld.com/2012/09/25/photography-tips-for-beginners-how-to-change-lenses-safely/

1. Don’t do this in a dusty atmosphere. Ideally, switch lenses indoors
   or sheltered from the wind to avoid dust or dirt reaching your
   camera’s sensor.
2. Lay your camera on its back on a soft surface, such
   as a jacket or kit bag, to protect your rear LCD, and so you’ll have
   both hands free to switch lenses.
3. Have your new lens within reach to
   minimise the amount of time your DSLR’s innards are open to the
   elements to stop dust getting in.
4. Use your left hand to press down
   on the Lens Release Button, use your right hand to turn your lens in
   an anticlockwise direction and pull clear.
5. Put the lens down to one
   side. Remove the dust cap from the lens mount of the replacement
   lens and put it on the lens you’ve just removed.
6. Line up the red
   dots on both the lens and camera.
7. Slot the lens in, turn it
   clockwise until your hear it click. Take the lens cap off your
   replacement lens and you’re ready to take some pictures!

**TL;DR**:
Do not do it in a dusty environment, don't drop it, don't bang it, do it slowly, keep it in a cool dry environment secured.

Comment: Most manufacturers and many other sources recommend that the camera be pointed down, not up, during lens changes. This lessens the chance of airborne dust from getting in the lens. Although dust does demonstrate Brownian motion, the Brownian motion it demonstrates is biased by gravity. Just look at the top and bottom of a shelf in a dusty environment. Which one has a greater accumulation of dust? the top of the shelf or its underside?

Comment: Agreed. But the effect is minuscule and likely not needing any such delicate attention.

But if you have a mirrorless camera or exposed sensor then go on, doesn't hurt to do so.

Comment: Any minuscule effect will accumulate over time and repeated numbers of instances. If you always hold your camera facing up and I always hold my camera facing down (and all other things are equal - we both always change lenses at the exact same times under the exact same conditions) the proportion of dust allowed into your camera compared to the dust allowed in mine will be equal to the proportion of dust on the top of a shelf to the dust clinging to the underside of that shelf. It is simple, observable, demonstrable, repeatable physics.

Comment: What do mirrors have to do with anything? The shutter curtain is what covers a sensor and protects it in either a DSLR or most mirrorless ILCs.

Comment: The mirror imitates an extra layer of cover/protection of dust settlement.
In a sense the dust will be more likely to settle on the mirror than on the curtain (which is the last line of defense)

Comment: The first time the mirror cycles to take a photo the dust is being dispersed all over the light box by the motion and the air that motion moves.